# Using d3 v7 calculate the y value of translate to place scale at right in container

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js

I am using d3 v7 to build drawing editor in real world coordinates(meters). To set the editor in real world coordinates I added following parameters for view box viewBox="0 0 66780 66780" parameters. I build my canvas so user can also draw in negative coordinate and on zooming and scrolling user can also draw beyond shown area.
[image]

I am facing the problem in setting y scale position to right. To place the scale in correct position I am using transform translate property. As my editor is bigger than actual width of canvas. So I cannot use width as value for translate y position.

How I can get the right visible coordinates at run time to place the scale at correct position while zooming and first time load?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I found out my viewbox values was not correct. My container height is less than width and I am my viewbox height and width is same. So following fix the issue

```
viewbox_width = (container_width / continer_height) * viewbox_height
```